# How to avoid AWS CLI error after installation

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have downloaded the latest version of AWS CLI and also installed it, but when I am trying to check the version in CMD it's giving me the below error msg

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you added the cli to your path? check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-path.html

Comment: Yes, i have already added the cli path, but still getting the same error

Comment: but wait...I thought your command was `aws --version`. debug doesn't exist as a command.

Answer (score 0):

CLI works for windows 8 and later versions. I get this issue on my older laptop , tried everything to make it work on this laptop.
Now it works when I had my OS upgraded to Win11..works like a charm a.

Comment: I guess upgrading the windows is the last option now